# Dropped PowerShot SX70 HS with lens full extended, now bent

Tags: lens, powershot

Is this camera finished?  the lens is fully extended, bent, and won't retract.  Camera tries, makes a horrible clicking sound, and then shuts down.  And I cannot move the lens back into position.

Comment: u_u Sorry to hear that. Take it to a repair shop and ask them.

Comment: I do remember reading someone's account of using force to re-align a lens, and in _their_ case, it seemed to work. If you find that there's no other avenue, you could always try it before actually sending the camera to the electronics graveyard. Wear eye protection, etc.

Comment: Re my comment... [SOLVED! HOW TO Repair A DSLR Camera Lens That Is Crooked And Jammed After Being Dropped #DIY #Repair](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_4K1Ge5COW8)

Comment: @osullic  What a lengthy way of demonstrating 'If it gets knocked out, perhaps you can click it back'!

Comment: Many people would be extremely wary of even attempting something like this with a consumer electronics device. The video is helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Since this camera is still in production you have a good chance of repairing it below the cost of replacing it in a Canon-authorized service.